# $(info) command io redirection

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, io-redirection

Can I get standard error redirected from make `info` command to a file? E.g. if I wanna print compilation command and redirect `2>` to a file, the file gets just an empty string but the command inside the `info` parenthesis is printed, like bellow:

```sh
ifdef VERBOSE
  verbose := @cat /tmp/compilation.out
endif

development: $(source)
    # Pipe to cat is just to redirect signals from make to don't exit on error
    @$(info $(CC) -o $(target) $^ $(DEBUG)) 2> /tmp/compilation.out | cat
    $(verbose)
    @cat /tmp/compilation.out >> $(log)
```

Comment: I noticed that $(), so long they are not variables, are evaluated to nothing when assigned somewhere. As it is probably a macro/binding layer expression. But Still, ain't there a way to get the evaluation of it without printing the code after redirection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make variables and functions are expanded by make before it invokes the shell to run the recipe.  The results of expansion are passed to the shell.

`2>` is a shell construct, it's not interpreted by make.

The `info` make function is defined to write its arguments to stdout, and expand to the empty string.  So, when make expands this recipe line:

```
$(info $(CC) -o $(target) $^ $(DEBUG)) 2> /tmp/compilation.out | cat
```

First it expands the arguments to `info` and writes the results to stdout, then it replaces the `info` function with the empty string, then it invokes the shell with the results; so the shell sees:

```
 2> /tmp/compilation.out | cat
```

The short answer is no, there is no way to get make's `info` function to write output to a file.  You'll have to use something the shell knows about, like `echo`:

```
@echo '$(CC) -o $(target) $^ $(DEBUG)' 2> /tmp/compilation.out | cat
```

Comment: Here's a tip: whenever you're trying to debug a makefile the very first thing you should do is _remove all `@` prefixes_ on your recipe lines.  This way make will print out what it's going to send to the shell and seeing this often leads to better understanding of the problem.

Comment: Yes, you approved my thoughts. I also find `--trace` option to be very useful in those situations.

Comment: I don't really understand that command line.  What's the `cat` command for?  You've already redirected both stdout and stderr, so the pipe seems not useful?  But, if it does what you want I guess it's OK!

Comment: At the end I just used this, which is not pretty, but it works: @$(CC) -o $(target) $^ $(DEBUG) > $(tmp_out) 2>&1 | cat; @$(info '$(CC) -o $(target) $^ $(DEBUG)')

Comment: If I would not pipe compilation command to `cat` it would send the error code to make and stop execution on this line where an error occurred, And I want the rest of task to get executed no matter of compilation errors.

Comment: Weird; usually one wants the build to fail if the compile fails, and if you want to keep going and see all failures you invoke `make` with the `-k` option.  In any event, a much cleaner way to do what you want that is directly understandable for what it is, rather than using a roundabout method like piping to `cat` just to hide an error exit, is to use `$(CC) -o ... > $(tmp_out) 2>&1 || true`.

Comment: Right, "or true" looks much less cryptic, I will use this. As the rest of the task is writing some compilation data to the log file I want to keep it running, it is pretty simple.